# Custom query with post_class filter using current_post not working

Tags: wp-query, filters, post-class

I have a new WP_Query on my archive page. I also have a post_class filter conditionally adding a class of `first` so I can display them in rows of 3 reliably.

This is the post_class filter

```
function sm_inline_post_class( $classes ) {
    global $wp_query;

    if( 0 == $wp_query->current_post || 0 == $wp_query->current_post % 3 )
        $classes[] = 'first';

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'post_class', 'sm_inline_post_class' );
```

This works fine for the default query, but the `first` class does not get applied to the posts from my custom query.

How do you conditionally apply post classes to entries from custom queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the global `$wp_query` not your custom query. Either declare yours global too like `global $wp_query_archives` and then use that in the `sm_inline_post_class` callback while being aware of the drawbacks of using global variables or do a little work like so:

```
$class = sm_inline_post_class( array(), $my_custom_query );
```

And then pass `$class` as the first argument to your `post_class` call (I imagine you are using this function on your archive page).

Then, modify your `sm_inline_post_class` function like so:

```
function sm_inline_post_class( $classes, $query = null ) {
    global $wp_query;

    $query = ( $query == null ) ? $wp_query : $query;

    if( 0 == $query->current_post || 0 == $query->current_post % 3 ) {
         $classes[] = 'first';

    return $classes;
}
```

This however can always attach you 'first' if you are using your custom `WP_Query` nested in a `$wp_query` which happens to have the `current_post` set to a multiple of 3.

The even safer option would be to use a different function to get the class name:

```
$class = custom_inline_post_class( array(), $my_custom_query );

function custom_inline_post_class( $classes, $query ) {
    if( 0 == $query->current_post || 0 == $query->current_post % 3 ) {
         $classes[] = 'first';

    return $classes;
}
```